# solve for time given distance, initial velocity, and acceleration

Tags: calculus, physics

I've been having trouble sorting this one out.  I need to compute the time it will take for a vehicle traveling along a straight line to reach a particular point.  I have the initial velocity ($v_i$), acceleration ($a$), and distance ($dx$) to the point.  I don't have the final velocity $v_f$ nor the time $t$  I've been trying to solve this equation for time ($t$) but that's where I'm stuck.

$$ dx = v_it + {1\over2}at^2$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You know everything except t in this equation. Therefore you should be able to re-arrange the equation into the form at^2 + bt + c = 0, the quadratic form. From there, you need to solve the quadratic (using the quadratic formula for example) to get two solutions for t. Since negative t does not make sense in this context, your answer will be the positive value for t.

Comment: Well, it's possible to get two positive solutions, in case $a$ and $dx$ have opposite signs. The desired answer is probably the smallest positive solution.

Comment: In this case $dx$ and $v_i$ are positive but $a$ can be negative.

Comment: It looks like there may also be the case where there is no real solution (where the discriminant < 0).  I'll have to deal with that situation in the software also.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use the [Quadratic Formula.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation) ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Thanks for the link, that's a very helpful page.